# GLMM for unbalanced design, nested random factor or fixed factor?

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model, glmm, glmmtmb

**The Goal** Determine if the abundance of ectos differ between sites.

**The set up**
The data is percent abundance of ectomycorrhizal fungi from soil samples. There are ten soil samples per plot and there are three plots per site, except for the last site which only has one plot ( I know, bad design....). Finally there are three sites. If I have to remove the last site with one plot I can. Currently I am running my model with plot nested within site. However I believe I don't have enough levels within the nested factor to do this? My current model is

```
m2<-glmmTMB(percent~site+(1|site/plot),data=percentabund,family=beta_family(link = "logit"))
```

I could change the nested random factor plot to a fixed factor?

```
m2<-glmmTMB(percent~site+(1|plot),data=percentabundunknown,family=beta_family(link = "logit"))
```

**Questions**

Have I specified the model correctly?

How do I account for (the unbalanced design)?

I really appreciate any help.

[image: Data is set up like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frst model:

```
percent~site+(1|site/plot),data=percentabund,family=beta_family(link = "logit")
```

does not make much sense because you have `site` as a fixed effect and also a grouping variable for random intercepts.

Also, since you have only 3 sites you would be asking the software to estimate a variance for a normally distributed variable from only 3 observations.

So, here you would want to fit `site` as a fixed effect, that is, your second model:

```
percent~site+(1|plot),data=percentabundunknown,family=beta_family(link = "logit")
```

---

Edit:

Following some discussion it turns out there are only 3 plots per site (with one exception). I didn't read the question properly :(

So there is a real problem here with insufficient sample size. I think the best you can do is:

```
percent ~ site + plot
```

with no random effects. That is, just a GLM model.

It could also be interesting to investigate the GLMM model:

```
percent ~ site + plot + (1 | site:plot)
```

With the sample size you have, I wouldn't be too concerned with residual plots. If the GLM gives similar inferences to the GLMM, all is good.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate you taking the time to answer my question. I am a novice at GLMMs. Just so I know understand the 2nd model correctly. Site is a fixed effect and plot is a nested fixed effect?

Comment: You're welcome, no problem :) In the 2nd model, yes, `site` is a fixed effect, but `plot` is a random effect. You can think of `plot` as nested within `site`, but that is not important here because we are fitting fixed effects for `site`.

Comment: Does the fact that I have only 3 plots nested within site and that its unbalanced raise an issue?

Comment: I have a set of abundances and I used the package DHARMa to simulate the residuals which look pretty awful. In my model I am using family=beta_family(link = "logit"). What steps should I take to make fix my residuals? Do I transform the raw data? Also when I run my model I get the summary. I've seen that you can run an ANOVA type three after.  When I am reporting the results of my study what do I need to report? Can I say the sites differ? Sorry for so many questions!

Comment: How many plots do you have ?

Comment: 3 sites and 3 plots per site

Comment: Ahhh. OK, you don't have enough plots to fit random intercepts for it. I will update my answer shortly.

Comment: I ran both models you suggested. m6<-`glm(percent~site+plot,data=percentabundunknown,family = quasibinomial())` and `m5<-glmmTMB(percent~site+plot+(1|site:plot),data=percentabundunknown,family=beta_family(link = "logit"))` . I got similar results with both models. Does getting similar results with the GLM mean I should go with those results?

Comment: I was curious if you could elaborate on what you meant by investigating the model percent ~ site + plot + (1 | site:plot) . If I run this model does this mean that site is nested within plot as a random effect? If I get similar results to a GLM Does that mean I just go with the GLM model? @RobertLong

Comment: No it doesn't mean they are nested, just that there is variation due to combinations of site and plot that isn't accounted for by the fixed effects for them. In your case if the inference is very similar, stick with the GLM

Comment: Thanks again! @Robert Long